# JS variables in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery code and a need to repeat it 4x times with changing index.
So I used for loop from JS and inside get jQuery code.

Am I using the right way to pass variables from JS to jQuery?
It should select elements .info-btn of parent elements: #info-box-pr-1, #info-box-pr-2, ...

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    jQuery("#info-box-pr-" + i + ".less-info-box .info-btn").click(function() {
      jQuery("#info-box-pr-" + i + ".more-info-box").css("display", "block");
    });

    jQuery("#info-box-pr-" + i + ".more-info-box .info-btn").click(function() {
      jQuery("#info-box-pr-" + i + ".more-info-box").css("display", "none");
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Don't worry to try it! ;-)

Comment: You are doing the right. No problem. For more clean code use string literals. ``#info-box-pr-${i} .less-info-box .info-btn``

Comment: The used id's do not seem to be [unique](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).

Comment: no - you need to learn about events delegation and not bind events directly on each element... https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is a framework that relies on Javascript, so you're not passing variables between them. You're simply concatenating the `i` value to a string, which is fine.

That being said, I would suggest avoiding incremental `id` attributes, as it leads to more code complexity than necessary.

For example, you could remove the loop and `id` and make the code infinitely extensible by using common class names along with DOM traversal methods (eg. `closest()`, `next()`, `prev()`) to relate the `.info-btn` to the `.more-info-box`.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.less-info-box .info-btn').on('click', e => $(e.target).closest('.less-info-box').hide().next().show());
  $('.more-info-box .info-btn').on('click', e => $(e.target).closest('.more-info-box').hide().prev().show());
});
```

```css
.more-info-box { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="less-info-box">
  Less info
  <button class="info-btn">More</button>
</div>
<div class="more-info-box">
  More information...
  <button class="info-btn">Less</button>
</div>

<div class="less-info-box">
  Less info
  <button class="info-btn">More</button>
</div>
<div class="more-info-box">
  More information...
  <button class="info-btn">Less</button>
</div>

<div class="less-info-box">
  Less info
  <button class="info-btn">More</button>
</div>
<div class="more-info-box">
  More information...
  <button class="info-btn">Less</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[You don't really need jQuery for this](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/). Use [Event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to handle things on the document level. For example:

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.id.startsWith('info-box')) {
    // hide all div#more-...
    document.querySelectorAll(`.more`).forEach(m => m.classList.add(`hidden`));
    // display the div with id #more-[id of the clicked button]
    document.querySelector(`#more-${evt.target.id}`).classList.remove(`hidden`);
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="info-box-pr-1">info 1</button>
<button id="info-box-pr-2">info 2</button>
<button id="info-box-pr-3">info 3</button>

<div id="more-info-box-pr-1" class="more hidden">more infobox 1</div>
<div id="more-info-box-pr-2" class="more hidden">more infobox 2</div>
<div id="more-info-box-pr-3" class="more hidden">more infobox 3</div>
```